# Regex to extract key, value by brackets #2

Tags: python, regex

I want to get key and value from text in a [key] value format:

1. key is not fixed, but it will be in brakets [ ] .
2. [key](there can be blank)value format
3. value can not have '[', ']'
4. value can have new line(\n).
5. value can be null.
6. last value can be only one line. (ignore 2 or more lines)

For example,

```
[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}[]:"
blah blah
[abc-def] this is also value.
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]

blah blah
blah blah
```

In this case, I want to get below pairs.

'AA' : 'abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}:"
    blah blah'

'abc-def' : 'this is also value.'

'BB' : 'abcd defg'

'CC' : ''

and my Python code is this:

```
import re

text ='''
[AA] abcd 1234 !@#$ _+{}:"
blah blah
[abc-def] this is also value.
[BB]abcd defg
[CC]

blah blah
blah blah
'''
pattern = re.compile(this is what I want)
result = {m.group('field'):m.group('value') for m in pattern.finditer(text)}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Probably `re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]\s*?(.*?)$', text,  flags=re.MULTILINE)` should work.

Comment: @AruneshSingh Thank you for your reply. But value (except last) can have new line. In Example, 'AA' value should have new line and blah blah.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need regex for this.

```
with open('input_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

storage = {}
for line in lines:
    split = line.split(']')
    key = split[0][1:]
    value = split[1:]
    storage[key] = value
```

What we're doing here is taking each line and splitting it on the first ']' that occurs. The 0th element of that split will be '[key', so we take the 0th element, from the 1st position in that element to the end, resulting in 'key'. Then the value is just the rest of the split.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But value (except last) can have new line. In Example, 'AA' value should have new line and blah blah

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing why that's an issue. This grabs the entire rest of the line. Do you want to keep the newlines? If so they're already contained. If not, just run storage[key].replace('\n', '')